# Bootstrap table for calendar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html-table, calendar

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap 4 calendar using a table for those with vision disabilities which will be displayed using full width & height of the browser. I succeeded with the someone's help in another post, but I used a span with absolute positioning which I think is a bit hackish. I want to use Bootstap 4 SVG arrows to select the "previous" and "next" month in the header area but the last row of the calendar keeps getting cut-off.

Previous solution using spans but works full width & height:
https://jsfiddle.net/2gb3a4ty/

Current solution which cuts off the last row:
https://jsfiddle.net/da79hwqu/

index.html

```
<table  class="table table-bordered vh-100">
  <thead>
    <tr id="monthHeader">

      <div id="header" class="d-flex align-middle justify-content-around mt-3">   
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left-square" id="prev" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2zM0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm11.5 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5z"/>
        </svg>      
        <h1 class="d-inline-block align-middle" id="month">January</h1>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right-square" id="next" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2zM0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm4.5 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h5.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L10.293 7.5H4.5z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

    </tr>
    
        <tr class="text-center" id="weekHeader">
          <th class="headerDay">Sun</th>
          <th class="headerDay">Mon</th>
          <th class="headerDay">Tues</th>
          <th class="headerDay">Wed</th>
          <th class="headerDay">Thur</th>
          <th class="headerDay">Fri</th>
          <th class="headerDay">Sat</th>
        </tr>    
    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="day">1</td>
          <td class="day">2</td>
          <td class="day">3</td>
          <td class="day">4</td>
          <td class="day">5</td>
          <td class="day">6</td>
          <td class="day">7</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="day">8</td>
          <td class="day">9</td>
          <td class="day">10</td>
          <td class="day">11</td>
          <td class="day">12</td>
          <td class="day">13</td>
          <td class="day">14</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="day">15</td>
          <td class="day">16</td>
          <td class="day">17</td>
          <td class="day">18</td>
          <td class="day">19</td>
          <td class="day">20</td>
          <td class="day">21</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="day">22</td>
          <td class="day">23</td>
          <td class="day">24</td>
          <td class="day">25</td>
          <td class="day">26</td>
          <td class="day">27</td>
          <td class="day">28</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td class="day">29</td>
          <td class="day">30</td>
          <td class="day">31</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

style.css

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#weekHeader {
  height: 2%;  
}

.headerDay {
  width: calc(100vw / 7);
}

#prev:hover, #next:hover, .day{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is autocorrecting the missing `th` in the `tr` of your `thead` and puts your `div#header` outside the table.

You simply need to properly use the `thead` tag, which requires a `tr` and `th` tag.
You can make it work with flex-box by changing the `tr` to `th` with `colspan="7"` but then the browser will autocorrect the missing `tr`.

Instead you can try this:

```
<thead>
    <tr id="monthHeader">
        <th colspan="7" id="header" class="text-center">...</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

`d-flex` Is not going to work on a `th` tag as it is a different type of display "table-cell" which uses the `colspan`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/ty875apn/)**

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank You !!, I did add `#header{height: 10%;}` just to make it look a bit better.